# Identifying rectangular structures on SAR image

Tags: sar

I'm looking through SAR images and I found this (see SAR image below).

[image]

And here's what it looks like on Google Satellite.

[image]

As you can see, there's no similarly shaped structure found on the satellite imagery.

Are these just some type of interference?

Comment: Have you compared imagery data of GE and SAR? Have you checked the surroundings for possible sources of interference?

Comment: Google satellite may not be representing the same time as the SAR image was taken. If you compare the dates of your SAR image with another image by say Sentinel-2 taken acquired at the same time then you may get some clues.